# SelectedIndexChange not firing in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using dropdownlist in asp.net which contains 10,20,50 as values.

I'm using gridview to display dataretrieve from table based on the value selected in dropdownlist.

Example, when I select 20, the gridview should display only 20 rows.
I'm using the following coding;

```
protected void ddlRowPerPage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtCurrentPage = sender as TextBox;
        DropDownList ddlRowPerPage = sender as DropDownList;
        int startRowIndex = 0;
        pager.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRowPerPage.SelectedValue);
        Response.Cookies[hdnRowPerPageName .Value].Value = pager.PageSize.ToString();
        pager.SetPageProperties(startRowIndex, Convert.ToInt32(ddlRowPerPage.SelectedValue), true);           
    }
```

I've 30 rows in table.

My problem is, when I select 50, it shows all rows. But when I select 10, the SelectedIndex function is not firing.

At the same time, after selecting 50, when I select 20, the selectedindex is firing.

What is the problem?

Here is the updates .aspx page coding:

```
<div class="pull-left">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRowPerPage" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRowPerPage_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" Width="60px" >
                                <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="20">20</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="50">50</asp:ListItem>

                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            rows per page
                        </div>
```

Comment: Is `10` your default value? Are you databinding the `DropDownList` on postback (e.g. in `Page_Load`)? Have you used the debugger to see if the event is triggered?

Comment: No, 20 is default value.. I tried it by changing to 10 also.. That time also its not firing.. Ya, I used debugger.. That's y I'm telling its not firing..

Comment: @Sakthi: what is the order of your `DropDownList Items` order? is it `10,20,30`?

Comment: Is your drpdwn inside form show aspx code for that

Comment: The order is 10, 20, 50.. 30 is not included..

Comment: @Nitinvarpe I can't understand ur question..

Comment: can u update ur question and show us ur .aspx page markup

Comment: what happens when you select `20`, once try by putting this on your page load `if (!IsPostBack){ddlRowPerPage_SelectedIndexChanged(ddlRowPerPage,EventArgs.Empty);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** as your items order is `10,20,50...etc.,` it is cleared that `10` is at first location and when you select the `10` as `first` selection `Index` will not get changed.

**Reason:**  `IndexChanged` Event only fires when `SelectedItem` `Index` is changed.
ut when you select some other item `20` or `50` and then select `10` it definitely fires.

**Solution :**

Add a Default item to `DropDownList` as `--Select Item--` so that whenever user selects item  `10` it fires the event as `Selected Index` is changed.

Try This:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="28px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="201px">
  <asp:ListItem>-Select Item-</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: he said he has changed selected item

Comment: When I select 10, after selecting 20, it fires..

But when I select 10, after selecting 50, its not fires..

Comment: @Nitinvarpe : Pardon me. I admit my mistake.

Comment: @Sakthi : i checked with your code it is working fine, are you sure that it is not firing after selecting 50 to 10?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is in not understanding when this event can be fired.. it can fired only when the index of the dropdownlist changed and that didn't happened in your case, because the first element when the dropdownlist rendered is 10.

In my humble opinion, the optimum solution according to that issue is rendering the dropdownlist in the page with a primer default selection like that :

```
<div class="pull-left">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRowPerPage" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRowPerPage_SelectedIndexChanged"
        EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" Width="60px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Choose--</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="20">20</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="50">50</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    rows per page
</div>

protected void ddlRowPerPage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtCurrentPage = sender as TextBox;
    DropDownList ddlRowPerPage = sender as DropDownList;
    int startRowIndex = 0;
    pager.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRowPerPage.SelectedValue);
    Response.Cookies[hdnRowPerPageName.Value].Value = pager.PageSize.ToString();
    pager.SetPageProperties(startRowIndex, Convert.ToInt32(ddlRowPerPage.SelectedValue), true); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add ViewStateMode="Enabled" to the DropDownList it should work.

Comment: "EnableViewState" of "ViewStateMode"..? Because, ViewStateMode property is not available..
I already set EnableViewState=true.

Answer (score -1):

I got information from here quite often.

I just want to share my experience this time and hope it might help someone someday.

I have a DropDownList in my GridView's PagerTemplate.

I used the example code from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagertemplate(VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagertemplate%28VS.80%29.aspx)

I used it in many of my pages. All works fine except one.

The OnSelectedIndexChanged event just isn't fired in that one page.

Later I set the "EnableViewState" of that GridView to false, it works finally.